# Django - subprocess call not working properly

Tags: python, django

I have these following views:

```
class MiniView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Automata
    template_name = 'convert/mini.html'
    context_object_name = 'automata'
    command = "python MiniDFA.py"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

class DFAView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Automata
    template_name = 'convert/dfa.html'
    context_object_name = 'automata'
    command = "python NFAtoDFA.py"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

class TransitionCreate(UpdateView):
    model = Automata
    fields = []
    [...]
    command = "python make_graph.py"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    [...]
```

For I would like the commands to execute everytime I call the view, but for some reason only the last one seems to be working properly I'm not sure why.. the script by itself seems to be working fine.

I also noticed that the scripts execute everytime the server runs, not sure why either..

Comment: see this related issue; http://stackoverflow.com/q/13303390/6396981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are classes, not functions. If you want something to happen on every request, you will need to override one of the relevant functions in the class. For example:

```
class MiniView(generic.DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request):
        ...
        command = "python make_graph.py"
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
        ...
        return HttpResponse(...)
```

As two notes:

- Using shell=True is probably a bad idea here. Don't use the shell if at all possible, it adds complexity when complexity is not required.
- If the shell script takes too long, the web client will timeout. Or the user will hammer the server by constantly clicking reload.

Comment: does this still work if i don't need the script to return anything, i just need it to run that's all

Comment: When do you want the script to run? If you want it to run in response to to a HTTP request, you need to return something (probably HTTP) in response to display to the user.